# What is the World Record for most push ups in 1 second?

Tags: trivia, training

What is the World Record for most push ups in 1 second?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because push-up records is not a recognized sport

Comment: From the [help center](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Sports Stack Exchange is for participants, hobbyists, and fans of **all [...] forms of competitive physical activity**." (my emphasis). Push-up records are clearly a form of competitive physical activity.

Comment: @Fillet Although it isn't a recognized sport, Philip hits the nail on the head with the Help Center verbiage. I haven't touched [this meta question](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/503/guideline-for-on-topic-questions-on-sports-se-regarding-activities) in a while, but it was an attempt to try to objectify what sports are on Sports SE.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe anyone keeps records for that short a period. To quote from [recordholders.org](http://www.recordholders.org/en/list/pushups.html), referring to the number of push-ups in one *minute*:

> it became impossible to judge about the correctness of the exercises at this speed. The last record that was accepted by the Guinness Book of Records were138, achieved by Roy Berger (Canada) in on 28 February 2004

Extrapolating from 138 in 60 seconds, you can probably safely set a lower bound to the record in one second of 2, but that's not particularly exciting.